# inf file for vcp in 64 bit windows

Tags: windows, usb

I am using the built in Windows VCP driver for a USB serial port.
The following *.inf file works for 32 bit windows (tried with both XP and 7), but not for 64 bit windows (though only tried 7). Could anyone point out where my mistake is?
Thanks!
Dustin Soodak

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=Ports
ClassGuid={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%MFGNAME%
LayoutFile=layout.inf
DriverVer=08/17/2001,5.1.2600.0

[Manufacturer]
%MFGNAME%=DeviceList

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12

[SourceDisksFiles]

[SourceDisksNames]

[DeviceList]


%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  Windows 2000/XP Sections
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[DriverInstall.nt]
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles
AddReg=DriverInstall.nt.AddReg

[DriverCopyFiles]
usbser.sys,,,0x20

[DriverInstall.nt.AddReg]
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,usbser.sys
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"

[DriverInstall.nt.Services]
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, DriverService

[DriverService]
DisplayName=%SERVICE%
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\usbser.sys


;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Device driver (64 bit)
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------


[DriverInstall.NTamd64]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles.NTamd64
AddReg=DriverInstall.NTamd64.AddReg

[DriverCopyFiles.NTamd64]
%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys,,,0x20


[DriverInstall.NTamd64.AddReg]
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.Services]
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, DriverService.NTamd64


[DriverService.NTamd64]
DisplayName=%SERVICE%
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\usbser.sys


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  String Definitions
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Strings]





MFGNAME     = "Company"
DESCRIPTION = "Product"
SERVICE     = "Product Update Firmware and Settings"
```

Comment: What is the error code device manager shows when you try to install the driver using this INF?

Comment: Just "driver not found in this folder". For 32 bit windows 7 and xp it finds the driver and you just have to press continue/ok once or twice and its installed.

Answer (score 0):

`DRIVERFILENAME` is not defined but is referenced in your 64 bit section. Try changing this to usbser.sys similar to the 32 bit section.

You can validate your INF file using the [ChkINF tool in the WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543461(v=vs.85).aspx). This runs a script to validate your INF is correct.

Comment: Oops...didn't notice that.

Comment: Still didn't work. Will see if I can get ChkINF to work.